# Batch file that runs a Public Function when opening an Access Database

Tags: database, function, batch-file, window, public

There is an Access database with a Public Function inside a module that gets called when a user types in a command in the Immediate Window inside the VBA editor.

Example:

A Module with a Public Function called: **Get_Exec(fDebugMode as Boolean) as Boolean**

To run this process, users would have to open the Immediate Window in VBA editor and type the command: **?Get_Exec(fDebugMode:=True)**

Rather than having the users type in this command on the Immediate Window to run the process, I'm trying to automate it similar to a batch file opening the database and running a macro.

I've tried a workaround by converting this Public Function into a macro using the RunCode trigger naming it  Run_Function_Get_Exec and then calling this macro in the Batch file... but to no avail. Is this possible?

```bash
start "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Users\Me\Documents\ThisDatabase.accdb" /x Run_Function_Get_Exec
```

Comment: To begin with, your `start` command is incorrect, it needs a title, even an empty one: ```Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\root\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "%UserProfile%\Documents\ThisDatabase.accdb" /x Run_Function_Get_Exec```. Without it, you are essentially opening `ThisDatabase.accdb` using whichever application the end user has associated with `.accdb` files, whilst using the title `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE`.